# Azure Cmdlets: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean

Tags: .net, powershell, azure, powershell-cmdlet, azure-powershell

I am using [Start-AzureWebsite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495288.aspx) (as well as Stop-AzureWebsite) azure powershell cmdlet to start azure website. It was working for about 3 months and stopped working 2 days ago (January 31, 2014) (without any changes to environment). Now both cmdlets crash with the error below:

```
C:\> Start-AzureWebsite -Name mywebsite
Start-AzureWebsite : String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-AzureWebsite -Name mywebsite
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Start-AzureWebsite], FormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Websites.StartAzureWebsiteCommand
```

I have tried to run it under different account & on different machines but without success. I also tried to install the latest version of azure sdk.

Please let me know if you have suggestions regarding this issue.

-Petro

Comment: What's the output of `get-AzureWebsite`? Can you see a list of you Azure websites?

Comment: @Raf unfortunatelly I am getting the same error. However some cmdlets works as expected e.g. Get-AzureSubscription

Comment: Check if you had any updates installed on your PC on 31/1, probably one of them messing with your shell. You could try and import the azure module into a clean shell `Import-Module azure`

Comment: What happens when you run a clean shell with `Import-Module azure` ? Do you get the same error?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tried different machines, it seems to be an Azure side issue.

I can't repro this problem with my account, but I have two suggestions:

1) Have you tried to start the service manually with the windows azure management portal?

2) Since the issue happened at the end of the month, could it be a problem of billing? (or something similar)

Answer (score 0):

The Powershell Cmdlets, like the API, use Certificates to Authenticate with Windows Azure. Check to see if the [Management Certificate](https://manage.windowsazure.com/#Workspaces/AdminTasks/ListManagementCertificates) is still available in your Windows Azure Subscription and that it hasn't expired.